# Query SQL table to find all columns carrying specfic value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to query a SQL Server table to find all columns with a specific value.

Column names are as below-

```
TransactionName,
Event1,
Event2,
Event3,
...
Event10
```

Value for every column except `TransactionName` is either 0 or 1.

I need to find all columns having row value as 1 for specific `TransactionName`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you expect your result to contain only columns that contain 1 or all columns in rows, so that any of EventN columns contain 1?

Comment: Please provide a sample output

Comment: Table structure:

TransactionName | Event1| Event2 |......|Event10
Transaction1    |   1   |   0    |......| 1
Transaction2    |   1   |   1    |......| 0

The sample output when searching for transaction 1 should be like:
Tranaction 1, event1...event10

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to unpivot

```
select id, col
from tbl t
cross apply (
    values
        ('Event1', Event1)
        -- ...
) c(col,val)
where val = 1
and transactionname = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE EVENT1 * EVENT2 * EVENT3 * EVENT4 * EVENT5 * EVENT6 * 
    EVENT7 * EVENT8 * EVENT9 * EVENT10 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
I consider that except  TransactionName all the other columns are of numeric type

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_NAME VARCHAR(128),
        @sql         NVARCHAR(max)
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE  TABLE_NAME = '<tablename>'
    AND  COLUMN_NAME != 'TransactionName' 
OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @COLUMN_NAME

SET @sql = 'select * from <tablename> where '

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  BEGIN
      SET @sql+= @COLUMN_NAME + '= 1 or '

      FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @COLUMN_NAME
  END

CLOSE cur

DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT @sql = LEFT (@sql, Len(@sql) - 2)

EXEC Sp_executesql
  @sql
```